# Comprehension information about encryption

Tags: php, encryption, amazon-s3, openssl

Let's say you upload some data to my server - files are encrypted by GPG or OpenSSL and moved to Amazon S3 - that's not really a problem - my problem is how to handle generated thumbnails?

When i do also encrypt them, upload to Amazon S3 or different space - i have to download and decrypt every time a preview is requested or similar.

How to handle that?

Comment: Questions about security or cryptography that do not include a programming problem are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

It is apparent that keeping them on your server does not require encryption. If it did, you wouldn't have the encryption method/keys sitting on that server where someone could easily download and decrypt all the files. So, why not make a thumbnail folder on your server and store the thumbnails there? The point of thumbnails is that they are small and don't take up much space. So, you should be able to store a lot of them on your server. Your change would simply be to make a thumbnail before you encrypt and send to S3.

Comment: Normally that's okay, but if i want to provide some customers space for hosting data, that's not the right way or? The keys are store AES encrypted to database.